# Rewrite authenticated Apache2.2 user for mod_proxy_ajp

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, ajp

I have a Tomcat connected via `mod_proxy_ajp` to an Apache2.2 instance. Apache does the authentication via `mod_auth_kerb`, and Tomcat uses `request.getRemoteUser()` to get the authenticated user.

This basically works, but I want to rewrite the user. However, none of the headers I set affect what is returned by `request.getRemoteUser()`, I only see them as additional headers, what do I have to do?

```
   # Rewrite Magic: change REMOTE_USER to something Alfresco expects
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteMap domain_map txt:/etc/apache2/rewrite-map.txt

    # Grab the REMOTE_USER apache environment variable for HTTP forwarding (requires sub-request!)
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.*)@(.*)

    # change the format and replace the domain, e.g.: 
    # user@some.domain  ==>  other.domain_user
    RewriteRule . - [E=RU:${domain_map:%2|%2}_%1]

    # copy processed user to HTTP headers
    RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
    RequestHeader set HTTP_REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
    RequestHeader set AJP_REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
    RequestHeader set AJP_HTTP_REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the headers are not being set as you expect them to be set, and they are getting to Tomcat empty.

I have experienced some puzzling processing order issues that caused `RequestHeader` to ignore the environment variables set by a `RewriteRule`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303018/239408 in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems the getRemoteUser() value can not be overwritten by Apache header directives, as the AJP protocol handler gets the username from some internal Apache structure. I worked around this by sending the username via http header and modifying the Java code to use that instead of using getRemoteUser().