# How do I write SCRIPT_URI to a header in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, header

I have a setup where I have servers like this:

load balancer -> Apache -> Tomcat

I would like Apache to write the url that the client used into a header, so I can read that once I hit tomcat.

I've tried to use mod_rewrite and mod_headers so do it, but with no luck.
if I look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html then it seems clear that i need the variable called SCRIPT_URI:

```
SCRIPT_URI=http://en1.engelschall.com/u/rse/
```

I also looked at this http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html so figure out how to write headers and have had some succes, but not enough.

I have php installed on the apache server, and if i look at phpinfo() i can see the SCRIPT_URI is there and has a sensible value.

I just can't get it to write it to a header. Here's a simplified version of what I've done:

```
#load modules
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#Get the original uri used
RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_SCRIPT_URI:%{SCRIPT_URI},NE]
RequestHeader set x-orig-uri "%{INFO_SCRIPT_URI}e"
```

I've tried several other options and both on windows, cygwin and ubuntu linux

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround myself, although it's not the clean and easy solution I wanted.
I was able to get the indvidual parts and can use them to build the full URI:

```
<IfModule !rewrite_module>
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule !headers_module>
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
</IfModule>


<IfModule rewrite_module>
<IfModule headers_module>

####### INITIAL SETUP #########################
    RewriteEngine on

####### SET HEADERS #########################
    #get and set the host name
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_HTTP_HOST:%{HTTP_HOST},NE]
        RequestHeader set x-orig-host "%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e"


    #get and set the host port
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_SERVER_PORT:%{SERVER_PORT},NE]
        RequestHeader set x-orig-port "%{INFO_SERVER_PORT}e"


    #If the uri starts with a slash and some alphanumerics, then make a 
    #group of that until the first non-alpha (ie. the next slash)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[\w-]+)
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-context "%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT}e"


    #If the accept-header contains a number after ;version= then make a regex group of that number
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \+json;version=(\d+)$ 
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_ACCEPT_VERSION:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-accept-version "%{INFO_ACCEPT_VERSION}e"


    #If the accept-header contains kasia2. followed by some letters, 
    #then make a regex group of those letters
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} kasia2.(\w+).*
    #Save the content of the regex match group ( %1 ) in an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_ACCEPT_NAME:%1,NE]
    #Set a header with the content of the environment variable
        RequestHeader set x-orig-accept-name "%{INFO_ACCEPT_NAME}e"


    #If https is on ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #...then set the protocol environment variable to "https"
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_PROTOCOL:https,NE]
    #If https is off ...
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #...then we assume it must be "http"
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_PROTOCOL:http,NE]
    #Finally, set the protocol header
        RequestHeader set x-orig-protocol "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e"


    #Get the request uri and set an environment variable
        RewriteRule .* - [E=INFO_REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
    #Build the whole original url out of the available parts. SCRIPT_URI is always null, otherwise we could have used that.
        RequestHeader set x-orig-url "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e://%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e%{INFO_REQUEST_URI}e"
    #In addition make an url with only the host and context, for convenience
        RequestHeader set x-orig-url-base "%{INFO_PROTOCOL}e://%{INFO_HTTP_HOST}e%{INFO_REQUEST_CONTEXT}e"

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://serverfault.com/questions/23470/setting-apache-environment-variable-on-mod-rewrite-rewrite-condition, you need to tweak the order of execution by using [different configuration sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html)

Here I added a dummy `<Location>` section

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=FOO:set_by_rewrite_rule]
RequestHeader set x-foo-outside-location %{FOO}e

<Location  "/bla">
    RequestHeader set x-foo-in-location %{FOO}e
</Location>
```

and these are the headers that I'm getting

```
x-foo-in-location='set_by_rewrite_rule'
x-foo-outside-location='(null)'
```

Note that I get both headers to null if I use `<Location "/">` (and that I'm unable to find a solution valid for all request paths)

Note also that [Sebastian's answer is getting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432236/239408) the env variables in the header without any dummy configuration section... Go figure!